# MySQL: loose index scan on RANGE and ORDER BY - how to solve?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing

### Using `index` for a range scan and `ORDER BY`

To keep it simple: I store birthday of users as a timestamp in column `birthdate` and have `timestamp_registered`, `timestamp_updated` and `timestamp_lastlogin` that I want to use for `ORDER BY`.

What I've read is that mysql can use the full index in case of a range scan only if the range column is the last part of the index. The same for using the index to sort, the column for sorting has to be the last one. This is a contradiction if you need both.

There seem to be workarounds to a range scan, e.g. using `IN (...)`, if not too many arguments are being used, or `UNION SELECT...`

Links:
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/10/using-union-to-implement-loose-index-scan-to-mysql/ and 
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/14/mysql-followup-on-union-for-query-optimization-query-profiling/

However, those solutions (using `IN` or `UNION SELECT...` won't work in my case, as the range of birthday for several years would lead to hundreds or thousands of arguments in `IN` or `UNION SELECTs`.

So, no matter testing with 40.000 or 2 million users in the database, one query (`LIMIT 20`) needs a few seconds. If I use `index` for fast sorting, the filtering is slow. If the `index` is used for filtering fast, the sorting is slow. Sure, as soon as more filtering applies (e.g. having `country` or any other arguments to apply), filtering will narrow the results and sorting becomes fast again.

However, there are sites facing the same issue out there and solving it fantastically... I wonder how? What could be a solution for this?

Any hint or idea would highly be appreciated! Thank you very much already in advance!